# C++ factory method pattern for abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, factory, information-hiding

I have to implement a factory method pattern in C++. The class (C) that is to be "assembled" by the factory is abstract and is inherited by some other class (D). So I don't want C to have a constructor. But to create an instance of D, C has to have at least a protected constructor. But then someone might derive from C and create an instance of C in this way. I don't want this to happen. So I created a protected constructor that takes a pointer to a C object for derived classes to use, code is below. The question is whether that is the correct way of dealing with this issue.

```
class C {
private:
 C() {}
protected:
 C(const C* c) {}
friend class CFactory
};

class D: public C
{
private:
 D(const C* c): C(c) {}
friend class CFactory;
};

class CFactory
{
public:
 static C* createC() {
  C* ptr = new C();
  ptr = new D(ptr); // There is garbage collection on the project, so no memory leak.
 }
};
```

Comment: Your code as-is will fail because D cannot inherit from C. You have made the constructor private. Nothing can inherit from C.

Comment: I don't think your method works: `class EvilC : public C { EvilC() : C((C *) 0) { } };`

Comment: How important is it to prevent somebody else deriving from C? Are you trying to prevent accidental or deliberate misuse? (Attempting to prevent the latter is generally a waste of time in my experience.)

Comment: Yeap, you are correct, a null pointer will bypass the mechanism. Now, that I think, only a type-safety-enforced language like Java could do something like that

Comment: I'm trying to prevent accidental misuse and to go one step further and make sure someone, following the "I'm just a too good hacker" mentality, won't just inherit the class to create an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a better option to give C a private constructor and make D a friend class of C.

Comment: Thanks, I really hand't thought of that, despite it being way smipler.

Comment: Creates a dependency from C to D though, when it should be the other way round.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to make sure that only D can instantiate C, I don't think there's any way to avoid a dependency in that direction.

Comment: Well, another argument against D being friend of C  is that it splits code for initializing Cs across both C and CFactory. Yet it appears this is the better solution

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are making a C object to copy in the factory?

If instead of:

```
C* ptr = new C();
ptr = new D(ptr);
```

you made D a friend to C, made a default constructor for D, and in the factory only had:

```
ptr = new D();
```

It would simplify things.